# How to enable cross-origin requests in Grails websocket plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spring-websocket

I tried to override the default configuration of the [spring websocket plugin](https://github.com/zyro23/grails-spring-websocket) for Grails, like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class CorsWebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry messageBrokerRegistry) {
        messageBrokerRegistry.enableSimpleBroker "/queue", "/topic"
        messageBrokerRegistry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes "/app"
    }

    @Override
    void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        StompWebSocketEndpointRegistration registration = stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/stomp")
        registration.setAllowedOrigins('http://localhost', 'http://localhost:8080')
        registration.withSockJS().setSupressCors(false)
    }

   // [...]
}
```

I also tried by doing a .setAllowedOrigins('*'), but it still won't work.

However, when I register my client, the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is never set on the /stomp/info endpoint. I always get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/app/stomp/info. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: did you define that config class as a bean? e.g. my adding it to resources.groovy as it is mentioned in the plugin readme? besides that, cors is enabled by default (so no need to setSuppressCors(false)).

Comment: Yes, I did. I put the CorsWebSocketConfig.groovy file in the src/groovy/my/package folder and defined a bean in resources.groovy as webSocketConfig my.package.CorsWebSocketConfig

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue using info from https://github.com/davidtinker/grails-cors. 
Grails-cors plugin is not working for grails 3.x, but there is some info in the repo readme. I'll copy/paste it here:

This plugin does not work with Grails 3. To handle CORS in a Grails 3 project you can just create a servlet filter somewhere under `src/main/java`:

```
@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    public CorsFilter() { }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");

        boolean options = "OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod());
        if (options) {
            if (origin == null) return;
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin,     authorization, accept, content-type, x-requested-with");
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        }

        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin == null ? "*" : origin);
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (!options) chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Reference the filter in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
     corsFilter(CorsFilter)
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I tried your solution, and even though the filter is being called and the headers are added to the response i'm still getting 403, any idea? (I've put my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460853/grails-3-cors-returning-403-even-though-its-allowed). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i pushed a grails-3.0.2/grails-spring-websocket-2.0.0 sample app to https://github.com/zyro23/so-30891198 which shows that it should be working.

```
curl -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080" --verbose http://localhost:8080/stomp/info
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080

curl -H "Origin: http://localhost" --verbose http://localhost:8080/stomp/info
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
```

and the second sample using grails-2.5.0/spring-websocket-1.3.0: https://github.com/zyro23/so-30891198-2

```
curl -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080" --verbose http://localhost:8080/so-30891198-2/stomp/info
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080

curl -H "Origin: http://localhost" --verbose http://localhost:8080/so-30891198-2/stomp/info
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check asap and will let you know if I find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In my setup, your first test command works. The second one returns : * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /stomp/info HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.39.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://localhost
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2015 19:57:40 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact